# Show past X days /var/log/messages using Bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, message

in BASH I can't think of a good way to do this but I only want to see the past 30 days of entries in /var/log/messages*.  The issue to me is how do I do that with just the Month and Day. For example:

```
Sep 2 14:26:13 <SOME ENTRY>
Sep 4 14:26:13 <SOME ENTRY> 
Sep 9 14:26:13 <SOME ENTRY>
Sep 14 14:26:13 <SOME ENTRY>
etc..
```

Any ideas ? HELP! ha ha

Comment: Any particular approaches you took? Any code you already tried? Any errors you encountered?

Comment: Yeah, I used a for loop and grep'd on each of the days that matched the last 30 days but that was for a different time stamp. So I tried it with this and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: for (( i=0; i<=${MAXSEARCHDAYS}; i++)) ;do
    egrep $(date --date "now -${i} days" +%b' '%d) ${USBFOUND} >> ${LOGFILE}
    done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## -- This works --- but ugly --

## -- Print only the searches that meet the date in each loop iteration (i.e last X num days)

```
for (( i=0; i<=${MAXSEARCHDAYS}; i++)) ;do 
egrep $(date --date "now -${i} days" +%b) ${USBFOUND} | grep $(date --date "now -${i} days" +%e) >> ${TEMPFILE} 
done 
sort -k1,1M -k2,2n ${TEMPFILE} | uniq >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is *close*.  This will give you a sorted list of entries (most recent first) through the start of August.  Depending on when you run it, it will give you as much as ~60 days instead of 30.  On average, I suppose it would give you about 45.  The other downside is that you need to adjust the `grep` statement at the end of the pipe as the date advances.

```
sort -k1Mr -k2nr <file> | grep -E "Aug|Sep"
```

Comment: # -- This works --- but ugly -- # -- Print only the searches that meet the date in each loop    iteration (i.e last X num days)
    for (( i=0; i<=${MAXSEARCHDAYS}; i++)) ;do
    egrep $(date --date "now -${i} days" +%b) ${USBFOUND} | grep $(date --date "now -${i} days" +%e)  >> ${TEMPFILE}
    done

  sort -k1,1M -k2,2n ${TEMPFILE} | uniq >> ${LOGFILE}

Comment: basically , before this step I generate a list of values. Then I go through and compare the it against the past 30 days in a loop.  but THEN you have to remove the duplicates because Aug 1 and Aug 15 will return same results.

Answer (score 1):

a little late but...

```
    egrep "^$(date '+%b %e' -2d)" /var/log/messages
```